# How can I access the name of the currently running test file from an event handler?

Tags: cypress

I need to access the name of the file with the currently running test within an event handler that runs before every test to log some stuff about that test. Like this:

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    cy.currentTest; // Doesn't have the test file name, only the names of a context and a spec
    logSomeStuff();
    return false
});
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Cypress.spec` for this. You can read about it from [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/spec#Cypress-spec-returns-an-object)

```js
it('log spec info', () => {
  console.log(Cypress.spec)
  // {
  //   name: 'filter.cy.js',
  //   relative: 'cypress/e2e/filter.cy.js',
  //   absolute: '/Users/janelane/Dev/web-app/cypress/e2e/filter.cy.js',
  // }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The `runnable` parameter gives you the following information

```js
title: 'my-test-title',
duration: 75,
state: 'failed',
invocationDetails: {
  relativeFile: 'path-to-test'
},
parent: {
  title: 'my-describe-title',
  tests: [other tests in suite]
}
```